# после обновления странички показывать начало сайта

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет) сверстал длинненькую страничку с анимациями на MDBootstrap, и если пролистать вниз и обновить страницу-она показывает это же место, не начало сайта, подскажите что и где нужно прописать что бы после обновления сайт сначала показывался.
p.s. гуглить пытался, нашел пару скриптов-не работают, или я не понял куда их "пихать", ну или я гуглить не умею:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать scrollTo(), чтобы делать скролл в самое начало. Поместите его в метод onbeforeunload, чтобы он вызвался до загрузки.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, работает))